# Get column as pl.Series not as pl.Dataframe in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to get the column of a Dataframe as Series.

```
df['a']
```

returns allways a pl.Dataframe.
Right now I'm doing it this way

```
pl.Series('GID_1',df['GID_1'].to_numpy().flatten().tolist())
```

I don't think that's the best way to do it. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand. This snippet runs, so it returns a `pl.Series`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [1, 2, 3]
})

assert isinstance(df["A"], pl.Series)
```

Comment: oh sorry, it works for me too.  I don't know what i did wrong before, maybe i used double square brackets and didn't noticed it. Sorry for wasting u'r time